# SQL server "Cannot insert duplicate key in ... The duplicate key value is (Sequence key)."

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sequence

Every 3-4 months we get an error on a duplicate key value which is a sequence key. According to our understanding this is a bug in SQL server that happens on average every 3-4 months. However, this week it happened twice on 2 different schemas. Coincidence? We can fix this easily by manually adjusting the sequence key and restarting it sequence at the correct number.

However, I would like you expert to give me some understanding

- IS this really a bug? What can/Causes this issue to happen? How can the sequence key be 4 numbers behind from one day to another?
- Is there any way to protect ourselves against this? Sinwe we are working with a schedule that loads all our projects/packages we have huge delay in time whenever this crash occurs.

Thanks for helping me out, I tried looking into this but couldn't find any reasonable answer.

**Edit** Sequence Creation

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [igs].[SQ_SK_ACTION] AS [bigint] 
        START WITH 180982719 
        INCREMENT BY 1 
        MINVALUE -9223372036854775808 
        MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 
        NO CACHE 
GO

CONSTRAINT [PK_TF_ACTION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [SK_ACTION] ASC )
   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
   ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] GO ALTER TABLE [igs].[TF_ACTION] 

ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TF_ACTION_SK_ACTION] 
   DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [igs].[SQ_SK_ACTION]) FOR [SK_ACTION] 
GO
```

Comment: I doubt this a bug in SQL server and rather suspect the root of the problem is meddling with the sequence start or bypassing the sequence by inserting values created outside SQL server. However there is no possible way to answer this without knowing any details about the schema and the code used for inserting.

Comment: There are [fixes available for the broken Sequence](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011465). Also, defining your sequence as [NO CYCLE NO CACHE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68354/5489) might help.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these fixes a bit more in detail. We are not running cycle. @Filburt, would it help if I provide the constraint of the sequence key on the table and the properties of the sequence key itself?

Comment: @YvesVanlathem Yes, it would really help if you provided these details. If you encounter this problem on an almost regular basis, did you already analyze the machine Application Event log and the SQL Server log to get a picture about the system state when error occurs?

Comment: @YvesVanlathem put the scripts in the question and not in comments; the question can be formatted, the code in comments is unreadable.